# How soon can I repaint a wall that I just painted?

Tags: repainting

I just painted a wall and I don't like the colour. When can I repaint it?

Comment: The time for recoating is usually on the back of the can. If for some reason it is not, it is 2 hours for latex, longer if it is humid or cool/cold, and 8 hours or longer for oil based paint. Same rule applies if cool/cold, under 50F

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the first paint job is dry...